# TFS report: How to show changeset list by team project?

Tags: tfs, report

Does any one knows how to create a query for Team Foundation Server that will show changeset records with team project name?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please at least try to do some research before you ask a question.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at creating a TFS report to report change-sets associated with different projects:

[Creating and Customizing TFS Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647430.aspx)